# Angularjs applying update to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So say you have the following code:

```
var absenceType = {name: 'hello'};
this.newAbsenceType = angular.copy(absenceType);
```

Now you make changes to `this.newAbsenceType` and you wish to apply these changes to the original object.

So ive been looking at extend:

```
angular.extend( absenceType, this.newAbsenceType);
```

However this did not do the trick.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `angular.copy` returns _"The copy or updated destination, if destination was specified."_

Comment: `angular.extend( absenceType, this.newAbsenceType)` should work. If it doesn't then you are doing something wrong which you don't show in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **merge**

```
 angular.merge(absenceType, this.newAbsenceType);
```

But extend also should work the same way the only difference between them is merge deeply extends the destination object.

Demo : 
https://jsbin.com/jucebix/9/edit?html,js,console

Comment: is merge a function from angular 1.4 and above?

Comment: Yes !! https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/api/ng/function/angular.merge

Answer (score 0):

You can use $scope.$watch

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return this.newAbsenceType}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  //do change
});
```